# Python not throwing exception when trying to update an attribute that is not available in the model

Tags: exception, django-models, attributes

Am using python 4.3 and django 1.0.2. When I try to update a field that is not available in the model no exception is raised.
`Eg x = Mymodel.objects.get(att1='abcd')`
`x.notvalid <---- raises an exception`
`x.notvalid = 'xxx' <--- not raising exception`

Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do an assignment:

```
x.notvalid = 'xxx'
```

You're just assigning `xxx` to `x.notvalid`. It is just python, it's like:

```
some_var = 'xxx'
```

Only you're doing it on the object `x`. In this case, `x` is a Django model, but it's also still a python object, and you can assign new properties to a python object like that.

If you try to access `x.notvalid` before you've assigned anything to it, it will logically throw an exeption, because `x.notvalid` is not assigned yet.

Comment: thank you rednaw but being an object of a specific model why the validations are not in place? Is this how it is expected to work?

Comment: Yes. As I said, in the end it's just a Python object. Django only does validation for properties you have defined as Fields. Django gives you the freedom to use all the aspects of Python while helping you out with creating your Models.

Comment: Could you accept my answer? Or give me an upvote? That's a way to reward people that help you out on StackOverflow.